# I am trying to create a function that opens a file for reading in C

Tags: c, file, function

I am trying to create a function that will open a file for reading.  Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//char* readRecord(char individual);
void openfile(FILE peoplefile);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *lname = (char *)malloc(25*sizeof(char));


  if (argc < 2)
    {
      printf("\n\nUsage: %s <name>\n\n", argv[0]);
      exit (-1);
    }
  else
    {
      strcpy(lname, argv[1]);  //copies the last name from the command line int \
      variable lname
      printf("Your last name is %s\n",lname);
    } 

  FILE *peoplefile;
  openfile(peoplefile);

  while(!feof(peoplefile))
    {
      printf("Hi\n");
    }
 return 0;
}


void openfile(FILE peoplefile)
{
  peoplefile = fopen("./people.dat", "r");
  if(peoplefile == NULL)
    {
      printf("Error opening people.dat file\n\n");
    }
}
```

These are the errors I get when I compile my code:

```
prog1.c: In function `int main(int, char**)':
prog1.c:34: error: expected primary-expression before "peoplefile"
prog1.c: In function `void openfile(FILE)':
prog1.c:47: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'peoplefile = fopen(((const char*)"./people.dat"), ((const char*)"r"))'
/usr/include/stdio_impl.h:30: note: candidates are: __FILE& __FILE::operator=(const __FILE&)
prog1.c:48: error: no match for 'operator==' in 'peoplefile == 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void openfile(FILE peoplefile)
{
  peoplefile = fopen("./people.dat", "r");
```

That is wrong.  `fopen` returns a pointer to `FILE`, i.e., a `FILE*`. If you need to set the argument for the caller then you will need to add another level of indirection as arguments are passed by value (copy) in C, so...

```
int openfile(FILE **peoplefile)
{
    if (!peoplefile) return 1;
    *peoplefile = fopen(...);
    /* ... */
}
```

I would prefer a function which simply returned a `FILE*`, and then your whole `openfile` function is meaningless; just call `fopen` directly, no need to wrap it.  In `main`, just use:

```
peoplefile = fopen("./people.dat", "r");
if (!peoplefile) {
    print_some_error();
    return 1;
}
```

Your code also contains an error; if you fail to open the file, you print an error message, but continue to use the file handle anyway!

Comment: i changed it to the way you told me to but when i call the function in main, i get this message

Comment: i changed it to the way you said but when i compile, im still getting an error related to my function call in main.  this is the error:prog1.c:34: error: cannot convert `FILE*' to `FILE**' for argument `1' to `void openfile(FILE**)'
My call function looks like this:  openfile(peoplefile);

Comment: @user3255899: Right, the signature changed, so now you need to call it like this; `openfile(&peoplefile)`. You need to pass a `FILE**`.  You have a `FILE*`, and the address of operator `&` gives you a pointer to *that*. However, please read the rest of my post.  There are more problems in your code than just this.

Comment: its :   v245-2% g++ prog1.c
prog1.c: In function `int main(int, char**)':
prog1.c:34: error: cannot convert `FILE*' to `FILE**' for argument `1' to `void openfile(FILE**)'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
openfile(peoplefile);
```

I'd use

```
peoplefile = fopen("filename", "r")
```

Replace "filename" with whatever file name you're trying to open for read.

Answer (score -2):

You can also change

```
//char* readRecord(char individual);
void openfile(FILE peoplefile);
```

to

```
//char* readRecord(char individual);
void openfile(FILE *peoplefile);
```

and implement as following

```
void openfile(FILE *peoplefile)
{
 peoplefile = fopen("./people.dat", "r");
if(peoplefile == NULL)
{
  printf("Error opening people.dat file\n\n");
}
}
```

Comment: That won't work.  `peoplefile` is passed by value, the caller won't see a change.

Comment: @Ed S. I am totally agree with you. File pointer should be reference type in my case.

Comment: No references in C, but yes, a `FILE**`.